# style view 'document details'

Tags: view

I am creating a new view for my SP data and I am using the style of 'document details' which is one of the options in 'style' when you edit your view. My problem is they are displaying 2x2 instead of 1x1 - see image attached. I cant find how to change this. Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution that I know off is to use some custom CSS to make the td's `display: block`. This will make the document details show underneath each other.

If you only want to show one item, edit the web part, click Edit view, then go to Item Limit and set it to 1.